# Compilation error since updating cocoapods to 1.0.0

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I updated cocoapods to version 1.0.0. My podfile look like that:

```
    source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/artsy/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '9.0'

inhibit_all_warnings!
use_frameworks!

target “my_target” do

    ...
    pod 'MagicalRecord/CocoaLumberjack'
    ...

end
```

Since the update i get compilation errors when trying to compile the pod CocoaHTTPServer, used by CocoaLumberjack. Attached is a screenshot of the error[image]

Issue did not happen before updating CocoaPods.

What might be the problem?